# 'return' outside function почему?

Tags: python

```
s = str(input("Как тебя зовут? "))
while True:
ii = input(f"{s},как твои дела? ")
if ii == "плохо":
    print("Все будет хорошо")
if ii == "пока":
    print("Хорошо, пока!")
    return
if ii == "хорошо":
    print("Это замечательно!")
```

Comment: потому, что `return` должен быть из функции, а тут её нет. Он тут просто не к месту совсем.

Comment: спасибо, разобрался

Answer (score 1):

```py
s = input("Как тебя зовут? ")
while True:
    ii = input(f"{s}, как твои дела? ")
    if ii == "плохо":
        print("Все будет хорошо!")
    elif ii == "пока":
        print("Хорошо, пока!")
    elif ii == "хорошо":
        print("Это замечательно!")
```

1. В первой строке `str()` не нужен, `input` и так берет данные в формате `str`.
2. Вместо несколько раз `if` нужно использовать `elif`.
3. Нужно убрать этот `return`, из-за которого и происходит ошибка - `return` можно использовать только в функциях (`def`).

Comment: Возможно, `return` нужно заменить на `break`, но это не точно, зависит от замысла автора кода

Comment: @CrazyElf наверное, да.